# How to jump to desired UIViewController using RESideMenu or REFrostedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This question is about a very popular Github sidemenucontroller project named [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu).

I started coding an application using [REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController) and it is working mostly fine.

However, by the arrival of IOS8, I think [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) looks more modern and is a better option for me.

I have got a small problem which I can't figure out for days now.

So from the leftMenuController, when a menu item(play) is pressed, I use this code to change viewcontrollers:

```
- (void) jumpToPlayVCversion1
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"playController"];
    UINavigationController * navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:navCon animated:YES];
    [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```

It changes to the PLAY viewcontoller with a nice transition but the "playController"s view shifts down by a navigationbar height(about 64pixels) for some reason.

Instead, when I use the below code for changing the VC, the "playController" is as it's supposed to be. However, there occurs two problems: 1- no transition (it just appears with no animation) and 2- the Application loses its capability of "swipe from most left to right for poping navigationcontroller stack or opening side menu"

```
- (void) jumpToPlayVCversion2
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewController;
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"playController"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[viewController];
    [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```

If somebody can show me a way to fill in `jumpToPlayVCversion3` so that the VC won't shift down and transition will be available, I will be grateful.

PS. I am using the project with storyboard.

Thanks,

Aytunc Isseven

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this in my project and it works very well. It hides navigation bar so the `playController`'s view doesn't shift down by a navigationbar height (about 64 pixels).

```
- (void) jumpToPlayVCversion1
{
UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"playController"];
UINavigationController * navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[navCon setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:navCon animated:YES];
[self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```